# Top Bar desappeared in Xubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu

What is disappeared is the `Applications Menu` with the logo of Xubuntu.
How to bring it back? I can use the terminal but I don't know what to do exactly.
I have just tried to reboot the system from the terminal but the bar doesn't return when the laptop is on again. Every suggestion is precious.

Comment: You don't need terminal for that. You an add items to the panel.

Comment: right, but it brings it to the right side of the bar

Comment: You can move it too using panel properties.

Comment: right! just answer the question so I can upvote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add any items you like to the panel and choose their position.

The item is called Whisker.

Use panel properties for that.

XFCE is very customizable ;-)